# Arduino yun wifi network not appearing in my available network on windows 8

Tags: arduino, arduino-yun

I'm connecting my Arduino Yún to my laptop via USB cable and as I read in Arduino documentation:

> When you first power on the Yún, it will create a WiFi network called
>   ArduinoYun-XXXXXXXXXXXX. Connect your computer to this network.

But in my case nothing appears and I didn't found anything related to this on the web.

I'm running Windows 8.1 on my laptop.

Any idea how I can solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

It sounds as if something is wrong with the wifi configuration on the Yún. Has it previously been configured? Try resetting the wifi by pressing the "Wifi RST" button for more than five seconds (but less than 30).

More info [here](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoYun#toc6).

Comment: thanks for reply, i click the reset button as you suggest and now the wifi network for Arduino appear with "LININO-codehere" and then i follow these instruction: https://www.arduino.cc/en/Guide/ArduinoYun#toc13 to connect my Arduino to my home wireless network, after i finish the instruction in the link above i was unable to access http://myusername.local any idea how can i solve this too?

Answer (score 1):

The question you asked is already answered by @mellbratt. You have successfully configured `Yun` and connected it to the network (configuration of WiFi by providing `SSID` and security key in web panel). The thing you have to do now, is to find what IP your `Yun` device is assigned on that network. You can use tools like `Angry IP Scanner` to scan the network and find your IP if you cannot access it from `myusername.local`. Using that IP you can access the web panel.